# Hyphenated word wrapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

Do we have character hyphenated wrapping supported in iOS? i.e. when text exceeds the frame width there should be a hyphen added by the iOS in the last word of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [GitHub project](https://github.com/tupil/hyphenate/) about hyphenation made by Tupil. It is a category implementation for `NSString` called `NSString+Hyphenate`. You may have a try with this. Tupil's blog ["Adding Hyphenation to NSString"](https://github.com/tupil/hyphenate/) describes how to use it.

You can also have a look at:

- [Frank Zheng's blog - Hyphenation with Core Text on the iPad](http://frankzblog.appspot.com/?p=7001)

Comment: External websites might disappear. You should post the answer here and add the links as a reference

Comment: Of course in iOS 6 this problem is now solved by the automatic hyphenation of NSAttributedString.